# AngularJS ui-router update parent controller model

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

So I have these states set up:

```
// Now set up the states
$stateProvider.state('collections', {
    url: '/collections/:centerId',
    templateUrl: '/assets/tpl/collections/index.html',
    controller: 'CollectionsController',
    controllerAs: 'controller',
    resolve: {

        // Resolve our collections before the state loads
        collections: ['$stateParams', 'Api', function ($stateParams, api) {

            // Get our center id
            var centerId = $stateParams.centerId;

            // Return our collections
            return api.get('/api/collections', { centerId: centerId });
        }]
    },
    data: {
        requireLogin: true,
        pageTitle: 'Collections'
    }
}).state('collections.import', {
    url: '/import',
    templateUrl: '/assets/tpl/collections/import.html',
    controller: 'ImportCollectionsController',
    controllerAs: 'controller',
    data: {
        requireLogin: true,
        pageTitle: 'Import your collections'
    }
});
```

If you look at the 2 states, you can see that in the parent state I resolve all the current **collections** from our API. This is then assigned to the **CollectionsController** scope (this.collections).
In the **ImportCollectionsController** I can get access to that data via the **$scope**:

```
.controller('CollectionsController', ['$stateParams', 'collections', function ($stateParams, collections) {

    // Assign this to a variable
    var self = this;

    // Get our collections
    self.collections = collections;

    /// --- removed for brevity --- ///
}])

.controller('ImportCollectionsController', ['$stateParams', '$scope', 'CollectionsService', 'toastr', function ($stateParams, $scope, collections, toastr) {

    // Assign this to a variable
    var self = this;

    // Get our center id
    self.centerId = $stateParams.centerId;

    /// --- removed for brevity --- ///

    // Save our data
    self.save = function () {

        // Import our results into our collections
        self.import = collections.import(self.centerId, self.results);

        // If the import is successful
        self.import.promise.then(function (response) {

            // Get our original collection array
            var originals = $scope.$parent.controller.collections.data

            // Update our original collection with the new imported items
            originals.push(response.data);

            // Set our results to nothing
            self.results = null;

            // Display a success message
            toastr.success('Your collections have been imported successfully.');
        });
    };
}])
```

Just incase you need it, this is my API service:

```
.service('Api', ['$http', 'HttpHandler', function ($http, handler) {

    // Private function to build our request
    var buildRequest = function (url, method, data, params) {
        var model = {
            method: method,
            url: url,
            data: data,
            params: params
        };

        return $http(model);
    };

    // GET
    this.get = function (url, params) {
        return handler.loadData(buildRequest(url, 'GET', null, params));
    };

    // POST
    this.post = function (url, data) {
        return handler.loadData(buildRequest(url, 'POST', data));
    };

    // PUT
    this.put = function (url, data) {
        return handler.loadData(buildRequest(url, 'PUT', data));
    };

    // DELETE
    this.delete = function (url, data) {
        return handler.loadData(buildRequest(url, 'DELETE', data));
    };
}])

.service('HttpHandler', ['ErrorService', function (service) {

    // Function to handle promises
    this.loadData = function (promise) {

        // Declare our model
        var model = {
            data: null,
            loading: true,
            promise: promise,
            error: null
        };

        // If our promise succeeds
        promise.then(function (response) {

            // Store the data
            model.data = response.data.result || response.data;
        }, function (error) {

            // Process our error
            model.error = service.process(error);
        });

        // Finally
        promise.finally(function () {

            // Set our loading flag to false regardless if there is an error or not
            model.loading = false;
        });

        // Return our model
        return model;
    };
}])
```

So in theory, when my **save** function is called in the **ImportCollectionsController** if the promise is successful I add the array to our existing array. What I expect is that if I navigate back to the **collections** state I should now see my new data, but I don't.
Can anyone tell me why?

**Update**

So I have changed my states to this (note the resolves)

```
.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {

    // Now set up the states
    $stateProvider.state('collections', {
        url: '/collections/:centerId',
        templateUrl: '/assets/tpl/collections/index.html',
        controller: 'CollectionsController',
        controllerAs: 'controller',
        resolve: {

            // Resolve our collections before the state loads
            collections: ['$stateParams', 'Api', function ($stateParams, api) {

                // Get our center id
                var centerId = $stateParams.centerId;

                // Return our collections
                return api.get('/api/collections', { centerId: centerId });
            }]
        },
        data: {
            requireLogin: true,
            pageTitle: 'Collections'
        }
    }).state('collections.import', {
        url: '/import',
        templateUrl: '/assets/tpl/collections/import.html',
        controller: 'ImportCollectionsController',
        controllerAs: 'controller',
        resolve: {
            originals : ['collections', function (collections) {
                return collections.data;
            }]
        },
        data: {
            requireLogin: true,
            pageTitle: 'Import your collections'
        }
    }).state('collections.create', {
        url: '/create',
        templateUrl: '/assets/tpl/collections/save.html',
        controller: 'SaveCollectionController',
        controllerAs: 'controller',
        data: {
            requireLogin: true,
            pageTitle: 'Save your collection'
        }
    });
}])
```

and in my **ImportCollectionsController** I have changed the save function to this:

```
.controller('CollectionsController', ['$stateParams', 'collections', function ($stateParams, collections) {

    // Assign this to a variable
    var self = this;

    // Get our collections
    self.collections = collections;

    console.log(self.collections);
}])

.controller('ImportCollectionsController', ['$stateParams', 'originals', 'CollectionsService', 'toastr', function ($stateParams, originals, collections, toastr) {

    // Assign this to a variable
    var self = this;

    // Get our center id
    self.centerId = $stateParams.centerId;

    // Save our data
    self.save = function () {

        // Import our results into our collections
        self.import = collections.import(self.centerId, self.results);

        // If the import is successful
        self.import.promise.then(function (response) {

            // Update our original collection with the new imported items
            originals.push(response.data);

            // Set our results to nothing
            self.results = null;

            // Display a success message
            toastr.success('Your collections have been imported successfully.');
        });
    };

    // Cancel our import
    self.cancel = function () {

        // Set our results to nothing
        self.results = null;
    }
}])
```

and I am still getting the same issue. When I navigate back to **collections** they are not listed.

Comment: what are you using in api.get()? $resource or $http or other?

Comment: $http but I have a wrapper around it which is why I have collections.data. Do you want me to post the code for that?

Comment: yes will probably help....but my guess is you are returning the $http promise which you should use to pull data out of to put on the scope

Comment: ok I have added it, I do use the promise to get the data :)

Comment: read this...explains how to resolve data from parent state of router to child state http://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-resolve-application-wide-resources-centrally-in-angularjs-with-ui-router/ thus you should be able to get rid of `$parent` and pass the array itself within the child resolve

Comment: I am fairly certain that won't work. I need to be able to change the collections, which that method won't work because it returns the unmodified model. Also, I don't need the child resolve to inject the parent resolve. It is already inherited by default so I can just call it by injecting "collections" directly into the child controller.

Comment: but you aren't recognizing that the array or object is passed by reference, it's not a copy... so it is the same in both and changes made in either controller will reflect anywhere the reference is made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, to fix this I changed my states to this:

```
.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {

    // Now set up the states
    $stateProvider.state('collections', {
        url: '/collections/:centerId',
        templateUrl: '/assets/tpl/collections/index.html',
        controller: 'CollectionsController',
        controllerAs: 'controller',
        resolve: {

            // Resolve our collections before the state loads
            collections: ['$stateParams', 'Api', function ($stateParams, api) {

                // Get our center id
                var centerId = $stateParams.centerId;

                // Return our collections
                return api.get('/api/collections', { centerId: centerId });
            }]
        },
        data: {
            requireLogin: true,
            pageTitle: 'Collections'
        }
    }).state('collections.import', {
        url: '/import',
        templateUrl: '/assets/tpl/collections/import.html',
        controller: 'ImportCollectionsController',
        controllerAs: 'controller',
        data: {
            requireLogin: true,
            pageTitle: 'Import your collections'
        }
    }).state('collections.create', {
        url: '/create',
        templateUrl: '/assets/tpl/collections/save.html',
        controller: 'SaveCollectionController',
        controllerAs: 'controller',
        data: {
            requireLogin: true,
            pageTitle: 'Save your collection'
        }
    });
}])
```

There is no need to create a separate resolve on the child states because they inherit from the parent.

With that in mind, I can change my **ImportCollectionsController** to this:

```
.controller('ImportCollectionsController', ['$stateParams', 'collections', 'CollectionsService', 'toastr', function ($stateParams, originals, collections, toastr) {

    // Assign this to a variable
    var self = this;

    // Get our center id
    self.centerId = $stateParams.centerId;

    // Save our data
    self.save = function () {

        // Import our results into our collections
        self.import = collections.import(self.centerId, self.results);

        // If the import is successful
        self.import.promise.then(function (response) {

            // Update our original collection with the new imported items
            for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++)
                originals.data.push(response.data[i]);

            // Set our results to nothing
            self.results = null;

            // Display a success message
            toastr.success('Your collections have been imported successfully.');
        });
    };

    // Cancel our import
    self.cancel = function () {

        // Set our results to nothing
        self.results = null;
    }
}])
```

and that has resolved the issue.